# Problem with selecting from database to complex type using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I try to use complex type if EF Core.
my table structure

[source code](https://github.com/se7ensenze/EFCoreTest)

```
User
-----------
Id (uniqueidentifier)
FirstName (nvarchar(255))
LastName (nvarchar(255))
```

and my class strcuture is

```
public class UserId 
{
    public Guid Value { getl }
    private UserId() { }
    public UserId (Guid newId) { 
        //check and assign
    }
}

public class User
{
     public UserId Id { get; }
     public Name Name { get; }
     private User() { }
     public User(Name name) {  
         //.... anti corruption 
     }
}

public class Name 
{
     public string First { get; } 
     public string Last { get; }

     private Name() { }
     public Name(string firstName, string lastName)
     {
          //anti curruption
     }

}
```

and here is OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .ToTable("User");
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasKey(u => u.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .OwnsOne(u => u.Name, un =>
    {
        un.Property(x => x.First).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        un.Property(x => x.Last).HasColumnName("LastName");
    });
```

every thing is work fined when I created a User and Save to database

but when I try to read it from database. the Name property is null
but again when I use .AsNoTracking. It work fined.
(I got from exception but I can't remember how to did it again)

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
var newUser = new User(name: new Name("Foo", "Fighter"));
db.Users.Add(newUser);
db.SaveChanges();

var u1 = db.Users.Take(1).First();
PrintResult("Case 1", u1); //output > Could not read Name from database

var u2 = db.Users.AsNoTracking()
    .Take(1).First();
PrintResult("Case 2", u2);  //output > Read Name from database success

Console.Read();
```

my print result method

```
static void PrintResult(string label, User u)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{label} >>>>>");
    if (u.Name == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not read Name from database");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Read Name from database success");
    }
}
```

**Can someone tell me that did I do something wrong ?**
**Why I have to use .AsNoTracking ?**

Comment: What is the purpose of the private default constructor and the `//anti corruption` code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. The problem is not reproducible with the code you have provided.

Comment: @Progman its "DDD like" entity i guess, when creating private constructor for EF, and public (with parameters) for others.

Comment: @TosZa BaaTeeSood Can you provide, what version of EF.core are you using?

Comment: With this sequence of code, the first instance from implicit tracking query is not really from the database, but your original entity, which can be verified with something like `Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(u1, newUser));` Why the property is `null` is a mystery though - are you sure there is no some hidden code doing it. These DDD concepts and their implementations for EFC always look suspicious.

Comment: @Progman It's "DDD", use for checking value before assign to property

Comment: @DmitriyKorolev It's .NETCore 3.1

Comment: here us my source code [link](https://github.com/se7ensenze/EFCoreTest)

Comment: @IvanStoev i follow this [link](https://altkomsoftware.pl/en/blog/create-better-code-using-domain-driven-design/).  but It's use EF Core for only when writing model to database.

Comment: @TosZaBaaTeeSood The code on your external site will reproduce the issue, but the provided source code in your question does not. They are not the same. Please [edit] your question to include the MCVE to the question itself, not on an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the issue does not reproduce with the posted model here. But it does with the one from the link, and the difference is the type of the PK property in the model - there is no problem when using well known primitive type, but you are using custom id class - yet another DDD "sugar", but with improper/missing equality implementation.

Without implementing value semantics for your id class, EF Core will compare it by reference, thus not finding the "owner PK" needed by the owned entity type. The no tracking queries have no such search, that's why it is "working".

The correct action is to implement value equality semantics in your `UserId` class (used as a type of `User.Id` property)

```
public class UserId
{
    public Guid Value { get; }
    protected UserId() { }

    public UserId(Guid id)
    {
        if (id == Guid.Empty)
            throw new ArgumentException("UserId must not be Empty");

        Value = id;

    }
}
```

for instance by adding

```
public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();
public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is UserId other && Value == other.Value;
```

Comment: thank you for help me to understand. and I will improve my question for next time.